# How to call Delphi DLL WideString Parameters from C++ (including var parameters)

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I have a Delphi DLL that works when called by delphi apps and exports a method declared as:

```
Procedure ProduceOutput(request,inputs:widestring; var ResultString:widestring);stdcall;
```

On the C++ side I have tried:

```
[DllImport( "ArgumentLab.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet=CharSet.WideString )];
 extern void ProduceOutput(WideString request, WideString inputs, WideString ResultString);

WideString arequest = WideString(ComboBox1->Text);
WideString ainput = "<xml> Input Text Goes Here </XML>";
WideString  aresultstring;
WideString &aresultstringpointer = aresultstring;
aresultstring = " ";
ProduceOutput(arequest, ainput, &aresultstringpointer);

Memo1->Lines->Text = aresultstring;
```

My console error reads:

```
 Unit1.cpp(13): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'BSTR *' (aka 'wchar_t **') to 'System::WideString' for 3rd argument;
```

I have built the DLL and the c++ test app using Rad Studio XE4 - it is a 64 bit DLL and APP

How should I have gone about doing this?

Best regards,

garry

Comment: There is no `DllImport` in C++Builder.  Are you using .NET PInvoke instead?

Comment: Remy,How do I obtain the DLL library without using the DLLImport?

btw thank you for your response.

Comment: @user2521117 If your not using C++Builder this may not work because C++ does not have a standard binary interface.

Comment: @user2521117: the point I was trying to make is that the `[DllImport(...)]` syntax does not exist in C++Builder (or in any other C++ compiler). That syntax exists in .NET instead for its PInvoke feature. To import a DLL function in C++, you simply declare the function normally like shown above and then statically link to the DLL's import .lib file (which you can generate with C++Builder's command-line IMPLIB tool), or you dynamically load the function at runtime using the Win32 API `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `DllImport` in C++. That is for .NET PInvoke instead.  So remove that.

The remainder of your C++ function declaration does not match the Delphi function declaration.  The correct C++ declaration is as follows:

```
void __stdcall ProduceOutput(WideString request, WideString inputs, WideString &ResultString);
```

Don't forget to statically link to the DLL's import .LIB file (which you can create using C++Builder's command-line IMPLIB.EXE tool, if needed).

Then, in the app's code, you can call the DLL function like this:

```
WideString arequest = ComboBox1->Text;
WideString ainput = "<xml> Input Text Goes Here </XML>";
WideString aresultstring;
ProduceOutput(arequest, ainput, aresultstring);

Memo1->Lines->Text = aresultstring;
```

The reason you are getting the conversion error is because the `WideString` class overrides the `&` operator to return a pointer to its internal `BSTR` member.  The reason for this is to allow `WideString` to act like a smart wrapper class for ActiveX/COM strings, eg:

```
HRESULT __stdcall SomeFuncThatReturnsABStr(BSTR** Output);
```

```
WideString output;
SomeFuncThatReturnsABStr(&output);
```

As such, it is not possible to obtain a pointer to a WideString itself using the `&` operator.  Because of that, the only way (that I know of) to get a real `WideString` pointer is to dynamically allocate the `WideString`, eg:

```
WideString *pStr = new WideString;
...
delete pStr;
```